# Duplicating (but not using) a materialized CTE makes the query perform as it should

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, optimization, postgresql-15

I have a large query with many CTE's and joins, and once I changed the amount of data in the database (from 20k rows to 10k), it started performing horribly: https://explain.depesz.com/s/TSu3

> Planning time     :   8.349 ms
>
> Execution time    :   69,457.005 ms

While trying to find the bottleneck I duplicated the offending CTE, but did not use it or reference it in any way. Doing this drastically reduced the time (as it should be from the start) to: https://explain.depesz.com/s/rODO

> Planning time     :   4.856 ms
>
> Execution time    :   545.418 ms

Is Postgres ignoring my `AS MATERIALIZED` on the first query as some sort of failed optimization?

I tried creating statistics, vaccuming, analysing, but only this worked

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Any chance you could add the data again to see how the the "original" CTE performs? Looking at your statements in the execution plans you provided shows that the the statements are not identical. They differ. Different statements will yield different execution plans. Currently it will be a hard question to answer. Could you possibly provide two identical statements with different execution plans?

Comment: I find it too hard to dig down to a possible core issue here. The description is too vague, also.

Comment: If you check the query diff (https://www.diffchecker.com/Z2karCsi/) you can see that the queries are identical except for the duplicated and unused CTE